# IN the utc zone MexicoCity is display as -5 and is -6 . This is afectin several Tradingview charts and Android Phones (local time)

Tags: utc

It seems that the library containing UTC time zones Mexico_City is wrong . So automatic detection display a wrong Hour. UTC-5 instead of UTC-6.

I expect that the libraries get a correction. I do not know from where are the libraries from but some tradingview charts are wrong and some android phones too.